Why is a link to a Teams meeting not working as an action in a messagecard?
Through Powershell, I post a message in a Teams channel with a messagecard that includes a link. Every other URL works fine, but when the link is a Teams meeting link, after clicking it, i get a message "This bot is disabled". I'm using webhooks, so I can't enable a bot. How can I get meeting links in messagecards to work?
I tried both adaptivecards and messagecards, all the same result.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We checked this at our end by posting a card via incoming webhook using powershell. We used the following JSON - https://i.sstatic.net/pB77bPFf.png. The meeting link is working fine as a button and as URL as well - https://i.sstatic.net/O9NzP661.png.

Could you please share if you are checking this differently?

@Meghana-MSFT thank you for looking into it. I have tried the same json you're using and the link/button is clickable, but when i do i get this: https://kappa.lol/pLj49.png Other urls open without a problem

I got it working. The code is good, but the app for incoming webhooks wasn't allowed on a tenant level. A bit strange i could add it to a channel and use it, and that other links did work, but by adding it to the app permission policy, i can now click the meeting link without a problem.
